# Transform a straight line into a curve

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

I have an equation which is a straight-line with negative slope from `(0, y_intercept)` to `(x_intercept, 0)`. Is there a mathematical transformation I can use to "curve" this line?

Stated another way, how would you create a graph which looks *similar* to `y = 1/x`, but has an explicit x and y intercepts?

Note, it doesn't matter what the function does outside the range of `0` to `x_intercept`.

Apologies for not knowing much math jargon, I'm translating to code.
Any help or tips or correction of my thinking would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  You mean like $y=\dfrac2{x+1}-1=\dfrac{1-x}{1+x}$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner yep that's it. A bit rusty on my algebra, I knew it was embarrassingly simple. Makes total sense now. If you post an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: You’re welcome.   Consider alternatively $y=\dfrac1{2^{x-1}}-1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$y=\dfrac2{x+1}-1=\dfrac{1-x}{1+x}$$ defines a curve that has $y$-intercept $1$ and $x$-intercept $1$  .

---

(I started with $y=\dfrac1x$ and added $1$ in the denominator to make the $y$-intercept $1$.

But that has no $x$-intercept, so I multiplied by $2$ and subtracted $1,$

to get $x$-intercept $1$ while maintaining $y$-intercept $1.)$

Comment: $x$-intercept occurs when $y=0$ and vice versa

Answer (score 2):

Update: suppose you want to create a curve from $(0,a)$ to $(b,0)$.
Then the following will do:
$$
\varphi_{a,b}(x)
:= \frac{a}{b} \frac{b - x}{1 + ax}
$$
for all $a,b > 0$.

---

To expand on @J.W. Tanner's answer: For any $a > 0$
$$
f_a(x) := \frac{a(1 - x)}{a + x}
$$
fulfills the condition:
We have

1. $f_{a}(1) = \frac{a(1 - 1)}{a + 1} = \frac{0}{a + 1} = 0$ and
2. $f_{a}(x) = 1 \iff a + x = a - ax \iff x + ax = 0 \implies x = \frac{0}{a + 1} = 0$.

Here's a plot for $a \in \{1,1.5, 2,3\}$ (for $x \in (0,1)$ we have $f_a < f_b$ for $a < b$):
[image]

If fact, the function
$$
f_{a,b}(x)
:= \frac{a(1 - x)}{ax + b}
$$
will also do for all $a,b > 0$ as you can check like I did above.

Comment: the $a$ in your update is different from the $a$ in your original answer?

Answer (score 1):

I did a lot of experiments to find the following general solution:

m = (y<sub>2</sub> - y<sub>1</sub>) / (x<sub>2</sub> - x<sub>1</sub>)

y(x) = y<sub>1</sub> + (m (x - x<sub>1</sub>) / x<sup>slope</sup>)

Where:

- y<sub>1</sub> is the start y point desired;
- y<sub>2</sub> is the end y point desired;
- x<sub>1</sub> is the start x point desired;
- x<sub>2</sub> is the end x point desired;
- slope is the curvature desired. 0 for straight, 0 to 1.25 for positive curvature, -100 to 0 for negative curvature

Some curves generated with the values:

- y<sub>1</sub> = 0.5;
- y<sub>2</sub> = 1.0;
- x<sub>1</sub> = 0.2;
- x<sub>2</sub> = 1.0;
- slope: -10, 0, and 1.25;

[image: plot examples]

With a few changes in the formula, you can create a decreasing sloped too:

y(x) = y<sub>2</sub> - (m (x - x<sub>1</sub>) / x<sup>slope</sup>)

Some curves generated with the formula above:

[image: decreasing curves examples]